# Remove HDD icon from dock in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, icons, external-hdd, ubuntu-dock, dock

Today, I updated my Ubuntu 18.04 machine to 20.04. My laptop has both an SSD (where the OS is located) and a larger HDD (where most of my data is). Since the update, an icon for the hard drive appears permanently in the dock. This was not the case before I updated.

[image: A screenshot showing that an icon representing my HDD, labelled 'Data', is present in the dock]

It does not have any open instances (indeed, it *can't* have any 'opened instances' of its own - clicking it just opens the HDD's root directory in the file explorer), so that's not its excuse for appearing in the dock.

Ordinarily, if I don't want a particular icon in the dock, I can easily remove it:

[image: A screenshot showing the context menu for the 'Geany' program icon in my dock, which includes an option labelled 'Remove from Favorites']

However, this does not seem to be possible with the HDD icon:

[image: A screenshot showing the context menu for the 'Data' HDD icon in my dock, which does not include a 'Remove from Favorites' option]

Of course, I could get rid of the icon by unmounting the HDD, but that is not an option - this is not some external drive I only use occasionally; it is a built-in hard drive containing nearly all my data and needs to be mounted during my routine use of the system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open `dconf Editor`.

If `dconf Editor` is not on your system, do:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Adjust the following setting...

[image]

Comment: Does Dash to Dock not have its own GUI for settings? I'm pretty sure it (and most other GNOME Shell extensions) does.

Comment: @wb9688 DtD is used for the DtD settings, which I don't have installed, or it's used for the standard Ubuntu Dock... as DtD is a superset of the Ubuntu Dock.